# Detecting when a user clicks on a webform loaded in a UIWebView or WKWebView

Tags: ios, webforms, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'd like to detect when a user presses a webform button present in an HTML page loaded in an iOS webview (ideally using WKWebView). **Is this possible?** And if so, **how**?

General comment:

I know that WKWebView has some limitations hence if you know a method that works with WKWebView please share it. If you know a method that works with UIWebView please share that as well as I can use it as start to find a solution for my WKWebView based app.

Answer (score 3):

To do so using WKWebView, you need to conform to [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/), and set the webView's `navigationDelegate`.

The method you're probably looking for is `- webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:`, where you can determine whether to allow the link touch or not.  You can get the target URL from `navigationAction.request.URL`.

A quick example:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
{
    if ([navigationAction.request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:kLocalContentPrefix])
    {
        // Show some local content

        // Don't let the webview load this URL.
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
    }
    else
    {
        // Allow the webview to load this URL.
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
}
```

To do this in UIWebView, it's almost the same, except you just conform to `-(BOOL)webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html).  But I would recommend using Webkit if possible!

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, demonstrated by shazron in Objective-C here https://github.com/shazron/WKWebViewFIleUrlTest to copy files into /tmp/www and load them from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The projects descriptions says "A test project to demonstrate that the WKWebView class cannot load file:// urls in iOS 8 beta 4 and 5 on a device". I don't get how I can use it to intercept the user clicks. Could you please be more specific?